# Regex redirect URL after word, slash, 4 digits in .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I need to replace:

```
https://www.domain.com/e-books/6002-XXXetcXXX
```

By:

```
https://www.domain.com/artigos/6002-XXXetcXXX
```

But not:

```
https://www.domain.com/e-books/XXXetcXXX
```

That is, only the urls that beggins with `e-books followed by a slash and 4 digits`

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^e-books/(.+)/?$ /artigos/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

And:

```
RewriteRule ^e-books/(.+)$ /artigos/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

But none works althoug I have `RewriteEngine on` in `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I can't test this myself I'm guessing maybe this will work

```
RewriteRule ^e-books/([0-9]{4}-.*)$ artigos/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

It's looking for

```
e-books
```

followed by a

```
/
```

Start of a 'memory block'

```
(

[0-9]
```

any number

```
{4}
```

four times

```
-
```

a dash

```
.*
```

Everything remaining on the line.

```
)
```

Close 'memory block'

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working, see for example: https://www.portal-gestao.com/e-books/6002-os-princ%C3%ADpios-do-lean-thinking.html

Comment: If you have other rules before this they may be applying before this one.  Do you have other rules in place?

Comment: yes, I have other rules before this one. I tried moving it up in .htaccess but nothing. I guess I can define a more generic rule: if after the slash, any word behind it should be replaced by 'artigos', not just 'e-books'

Comment: Oops...  did we escape the /'s try: 
RewriteRule ^e-books\/([0-9]{4}-.*)$ artigos/$1 [NC,R,L]...

My test https://regex101.com/r/eT5fR9/1

Also, if you have not already, take a look at the rewrite flags https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html
To make sure you're not calling a "Last" before getting to this rule, or maybe Chaining the rules in a strange way. Let us know if this helps! :)

Comment: Ok, this is redirecting to https://www.portal-gestao.com/home/portalge/public_html/artigos/6002-os-princ%c3%adpios-do-lean-thinking.html It should redirect to https://www.portal-gestao.com/artigos/6002-os-princ%c3%adpios-do-lean-thinking.html

Comment: I think this is working... RewriteRule ^e-books\/([0-9]{4}-.*)$ /artigos/$1 [NC,R,L]

Comment: Ok, If those URI's you sent are correct, then the problem is the ^ at the start of the line.  It tells the REGEX that this line starts with e-books. so (.*?e-books\/([0-9]{4}-.*)$ /artigox/$1  should fix the issues...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this URL:

```
RewriteRule ^e-books/(\d{4}-.+)/?$ /artigos/$1 [NC,R=302,L]
```

`(\d{4}-.+)` makes sure there are 4 digits and a hyphen after `e-books/`

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working, see for example: https://www.portal-gestao.com/e-books/6002-os-princ%C3%ADpios-do-lean-thinking.html

Comment: Same rules works on my Apache. Make sure to keep this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line.